# Are my file (PHP,pictures,script) protected from download?

Tags: php, security

I am building a website on localhost for now. My files are in the www folder.
Directly inside www, I have the index.php and more php pages.

I have also some folder like pictures/ which contains pictures submitted by users; css/ with all the css files; js/ width all the js files and includes/ with some PHP files

My problem is that when I input in the browser localhost/pictures, I see the list of all my pictures. Same thing for localhost/css , localhsot/js or localhost/includes. You have the list of all my file. and it means it could be easy for a robot to download all my files , except the PHP files (which, for some reason, are not downloaded properly : PHP code is not accessible).

[image: You can see all my pictures by entering localhost/pictures]

Is there a way to prevent access to the main directory for the users ? I thought about writing an index.php file inside www/pictures that redirects to the index.php of www. I don't know anything about best practice in term of structure/organization of folder for a website.

Thanks

Comment: You could always turn directory listing off in your `.htaccess`? Similarly, use `robots.txt` to prevent robot access.

Comment: What @BenM said. Also, if you disable access to scripts and images (as in file permissions), people who visit your webpage are not able to view them.

Comment: Do you need those images available at all? Are they used on your site somewhere? Keep in mind that everything you want to show to the user via his browser has to be accessible for the browser. It's ok to disable the directory listing, if you don't want people browsing the files. But if you need them somewhere, you can't deny access to them.

Comment: Yes indeed, I need access to them. I know that everything that the browser display will be accessible to the user, I dont want them to be able to see th whole list of image directly because one could write an easy script to get all the pictures. Options All - indexes seems to work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sol 1 :**

*you can put a .htaccess file in that folder that contains just:*

```
deny from all
```

That way you cannot open any file from that folder, but you can include them in php without any problems.

**Sol 2 :**

```
# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: If he wants to display any of the images on his site, however, this will effectievly force him to write a PHP script that will read image files from this folder.

Comment: Sol 1 is not option since i Use the images in my code. I tested to put this inside /css and js/ directory and I have no more style. Sol 2 is working fine but it display a message "Forbiden". Is there a way to redirect to my own "forbidden page".

Answer (score 2):

You can force Apache to show a forbidden message when someone tries to browse your indexes by placing a `.htaccess` file inside all of the directories you wish to prevent browsing.

Inside your `.htaccess`, add the following:

```
# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

Similarly, you can create a `robots.txt` file inside your web root, and add the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /pictures/
Disallow: /css/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /includes/
```

You should of course be aware of the SEO implications of prevent robot access to your images.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to your .htaccess to your main project folder

```
# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Put user specific data in a folder outside of your web root.